# Detecting that SMS failed to be sent on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

In my app, it is very important to know whether SMS has been sent or not. For checking, I am using this delegate method:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{

    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled: {
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(SMScancelled) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        }
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent: {
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(SMSsent) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        }
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed: {
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(SMSfailed) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My problem is, that when testing, I turn on Airplane mode in settings (to test what will happen) and then I am trying to send SMS (using my app). Naturally, iOS fails to send it and system informs me about that. In message app, it is also shown, that I have failed to send it. But delegate method still returns MessageComposeResultSent instead of MessageComposeResultFailed. This situation also happens when I test on another phone that has no SIM card.

I am testing this on iOS 7 and iOS 8.

In documentation, there is written, that MessageComposeResultSent means "The user successfully queued or sent the message". This means, behaviour I am expecting is correct.

So how to know, whether my last SMS has been succesfully sent, or that sending has failed?

Comment: Were you able to check it ? I am also facing the same issue. Any idea when this delegate MessageComposeResultFailed gets fired?

Comment: Sadly, I do not remember, as it happened 5 years ago and now I am no longer iOS developer, so I am not able to test it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify if the device is allowed to send text message by using the `canSendText` method of the `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Add this below code when you care sending the message  (This method detects of your device does not support SMS)

```
if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [warningAlert show];
    return;
}
```

You can check Message failed by using delegate method of `MFMessageComposeViewController`

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result
{
    switch (result) {
       case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
       break;

       case MessageComposeResultFailed:
       {
            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to send SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
            break;
       }

       case MessageComposeResultSent:
           break;

       default:
           break;
   }

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know about method canSendText, but this alone is not enought. I can test it before opening of MFMessageComposeView and it can return TRUE, but when the user will attempt to send SMS, device can loose signal and will fail sending.

I am using messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult, but its behaviour is not as I need (it is mentioned in answer).

Comment: what you want then ? if device losses the signal then it will return `MessageComposeResultFailed`

Comment: If that would be true, why it is returning MessageComposeResultSent, when I try to send when Airplane mode is on? Or is this different behaviour than loosing signal?

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting sent but I getting correct output

Comment: It might be due to different iOS. I am trying this on iOS 8 (do not have access to iOS 9 device today).

Comment: hmm might be possible, it looks like bug of iOS you can upgrade to new version will fixes your problem

Comment: This will only hide it, as there are still iOS 8 users (over 7% of users in another app) that fill get wrong information.

Comment: When the delegate is called with a value of `MessageComposeResultSent`, it just means that the user chose to send.  Subsequent failure isn't reported.

Comment: @MayankPatel I too face the issue ... in iOS 13 too if I am putting Airplane mode on or disabling the SIM, I get 'MessageComposeResultSent' . can you please tell when this MessageComposeResultFailed will be fired?

Comment: @Fionashoff it went to outbox and when you connect with the internet again then that mail will be delivered that is how it should work.

Comment: @MayankPatel But I am not talking about mail / I am talking about SMS.. So at which case MessageComposeResultFailed will be fired. I am behind this for few days. I just need a test case to make testing team understand

Comment: @MayankPatel I am using MFMessage controller which is different from Mail.